# How to trigger cap touch sensor without touching it?

Tags: capacitance, capsense, touch

I have a device that has metal spring connected to microcontroller pin that has in-built cap touch sensing . This spring is used to turn the device on and off. I plan to place the device in unreachable area so I want it to start working every time it gets voltage on it without having to press ON/OFF button (touch the spring). My question is what do I need to do to trigger the cap touch pin one time when the device receives power supply? I would use regular switch to turn power supply to device on and off.

Comment: You should add the type of sensor/microcontroller you are using otherwise the question can't be answered (the answer will either be to use a chip which allows touch-free cap sense or to set up something different in the MCU if the MCU's sensing can be touch-free)

Comment: Changing the code isnt an option since I cant find what type of chip it is (cant read any marks on it, probably faded). Only option is to try and simulate touch every time I get the power on if possible. I figured it was chip with in built cap sensing because spring is connected straight to the chip pin.

Comment: ah, you want to trigger it automatically not just without touching it.

Comment: Yeah I want it to be triggered once every time I turn the power on the device.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triggering a capacitive sensor electronically?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/19435/triggering-a-capacitive-sensor-electronically)